# How is Lisp's read-eval-print loop different than Python's?

Tags: python, functional-programming, lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I've encounter a following [statement by Richard Stallman](http://stallman.org/stallman-computing.html):

> 'When you start a Lisp system, it enters a read-eval-print loop. Most other languages have nothing comparable to read, nothing comparable to eval, and nothing comparable to print. What gaping deficiencies! '

Now, I did very little programming in Lisp, but I've wrote considerable amount of code in Python and recently a little in Erlang. My impression was that these languages also offer read-eval-print loop, but Stallman disagrees (at least about Python):

> 'I skimmed documentation of Python after people told me it was fundamentally similar to Lisp. My conclusion is that that is not so. When you start Lisp, it does 'read', 'eval', and 'print', all of which are missing in Python.'

Is there really a fundamental technical difference between Lisp's and Python's read-eval-print loops? Can you give examples of things that Lisp REPL makes easy and that are difficult to do in Python?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In support of Stallman's position, Python does not do the same thing as typical Lisp systems in the following areas:

- The `read` function in Lisp reads an S-expression, which represents an arbitrary data structure that can either be treated as data, or evaluated as code. The closest thing in Python reads a single string, which you would have to parse yourself if you want it to mean anything.
- The `eval` function in Lisp can execute any Lisp code. The `eval` function in Python evaluates *only* expressions, and needs the `exec` statement to run statements. But both these work with Python source code represented as text, and you have to jump through a bunch of hoops to "eval" a Python AST.
- The `print` function in Lisp writes out an S-expression in exactly the same form that `read` accepts. `print` in Python prints out something defined by the data you're trying to print, which is certainly not always reversible.

Stallman's statement is a bit disingenuous, because clearly Python *does* have functions named exactly `eval` and `print`, but they do something different (and inferior) to what he expects.

In my opinion, Python *does* have some aspects similar to Lisp, and I can understand why people might have recommended that Stallman look into Python. However, as [Paul Graham argues in What Made Lisp Different](http://www.paulgraham.com/diff.html), any programming language that includes all the capabilities of Lisp, must also *be* Lisp.

Comment: Indeed, RMS may have preferred for `print()` to use `repr()`     instead of `str()`. That said, `print(repr(eval(raw_input("> "))))` is pretty close to a REPL.

Comment: Note that `eval` and `exec` also work with code objects (returned by `compile`), not only strings.

Comment: @user4815162342: Yes, that's what I meant by "jump through a bunch of hoops".

Comment: Python makes a distinction between data and code. LISP doesn't.  See also [Greenspun's tenth rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun's_tenth_rule)

Comment: A single call to `compile` is hardly a bunch of hoops. Stallman's point is that Python is missing the *concept* of the reader and the flexibility it provides in handling of data-as-code, not that Python makes it hard to provide `eval` with something other than a string.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Does it though? Python has first-class code representations; lisp takes textual input in the form of sequences of characters.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, not all Lisps are equal. See the syntax object definition in R6RS.

Comment: But the python interactive prompt doesn't read "a single string". It reads a complete expression (often over several lines), which can evaluate to data or code (an expression or a statement). Since functions are first-class objects in python, the equivalent of `eval` is to simply run the object: `name()`, if `name` refers to a function. Only `print` does indeed have different properties: printing a python expression or function does not usually give us something that can be parsed the same way again.

Comment: Stallman is known for having these kinds of... high standards.

Answer (score 33):

Stallman's point is that not implementing an explicit "reader" makes Python's REPL appear crippled compared to Lisps because it removes a crucial step from the REPL process. Reader is the component that transforms a textual input stream into the memory — think of something like an XML parser built into the language and used for both source code *and* for data. This is useful not only for writing macros (which would in theory be possible in Python with the `ast` module), but also for debugging and introspection.

Say you're interested in how the `incf` special form is implemented. You can test it like this:

```
[4]> (macroexpand '(incf a))
(SETQ A (+ A 1)) ;
```

But `incf` can do much more than incrementing symbol values. What exactly does it do when asked to increment a hash table entry? Let's see:

```
[2]> (macroexpand '(incf (gethash htable key)))
(LET* ((#:G3069 HTABLE) (#:G3070 KEY) (#:G3071 (+ (GETHASH #:G3069 #:G3070) 1)))
 (SYSTEM::PUTHASH #:G3069 #:G3070 #:G3071)) ;
```

Here we learn that `incf` calls a system-specific `puthash` function, which is an implementation detail of this Common Lisp system. Note how the "printer" is making use of features known to the "reader", such as introducing anonymous symbols with the `#:` syntax, and referring to the same symbols within the scope of the expanded expression. Emulating this kind of inspection in Python would be much more verbose and less accessible.

In addition to the obvious uses at the REPL, experienced Lispers use `print` and `read` in the code as a simple and readily available serialization tool, comparable to XML or json. While Python has the `str` function, equivalent to Lisp's `print`, it lacks the equivalent of `read`, the closest equivalent being `eval`. `eval` of course conflates *two* different concepts, parsing and evaluation, which leads to [problems like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary) and [solutions like this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/364469-safe-eval/) and is a recurring topic on Python forums. This would not be an issue in Lisp precisely because the reader and the evaluator are cleanly separated.

Finally, advanced features of the reader facility enable the programmer to extend the language in ways that even macros could not otherwise provide. A perfect example of such making hard things possible is [the `infix` package](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/code/syntax/infix/infix.cl) by Mark Kantrowitz, implementing a full-featured infix syntax as a reader macro.

Answer (score 22):

In a Lisp-based system one typically develops the program while it is running from the REPL (read eval print loop). So it integrates a bunch of tools: completion, editor, command-line-interpreter, debugger, ... The default is to have that. Type an expression with an error - you are in another REPL level with some debugging commands enabled. You actually have to do something to get rid of this behavior.

You can have two different meanings of the REPL concept:

- the Read Eval Print Loop like in Lisp (or a few other similar languages). It reads programs and data, it evaluates and prints the result data. Python does not work this way. Lisp's REPL allows you to work directly in a meta-programming way, writing code which generates (code), check the expansions, transform actual code, etc.. Lisp has read/eval/print as the top loop. Python has something like readstring/evaluate/printstring as the top-loop.
- the Command Line Interface. An interactive shell. See for example for [IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/index.html). Compare that to Common Lisp's [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/index.html#Top).

The default shell of Python in default mode is not really that powerful for interactive use:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a+2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

You get an error message and that's it.

Compare that to the CLISP REPL:

```
rjmba:~ joswig$ clisp
  i i i i i i i       ooooo    o        ooooooo   ooooo   ooooo
  I I I I I I I      8     8   8           8     8     o  8    8
  I  \ `+' /  I      8         8           8     8        8    8
   \  `-+-'  /       8         8           8      ooooo   8oooo
    `-__|__-'        8         8           8           8  8
        |            8     o   8           8     o     8  8
  ------+------       ooooo    8oooooo  ooo8ooo   ooooo   8

Welcome to GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07) <http://clisp.cons.org/>

Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Michael Stoll 1992, 1993
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Marcus Daniels 1994-1997
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Pierpaolo Bernardi, Sam Steingold 1998
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Sam Steingold 1999-2000
Copyright (c) Sam Steingold, Bruno Haible 2001-2010

Type :h and hit Enter for context help.

[1]> (+ a 2)

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable A has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of A.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for A.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
Break 1 [2]>
```

CLISP uses Lisp's condition system to break into a debugger REPL. It presents some restarts. Within the error context, the new REPL provides extended commands.

Let's use the `:R1` restart:

```
Break 1 [2]> :r1
Use instead of A> 2
4
[3]>
```

Thus you get interactive repair of programs and execution runs...

Comment: Yes, but the thing about python is that the interpreter prompt *does* facilitate interactive development. It really sounds like RMS looked at python, concluded correctly that it is not in fact lisp, and declared it inferior.

Comment: @Marcin, it does. But the default 'interpreter' prompt is not very powerful for interactive development. Just as a CLI, not as a REPL which reads/evals/prints. Stallman was coming from a world where the interactive prompt had much more functionality. Including his own Emacs.

Comment: In practice, in my own experience, I would not say that the Common Lisp repl is more helpful by itself.

Comment: @Marcin: Common Lisp is a language. The REPL is barely defined in the language spec. Which REPL of which implementation do you think of?

Comment: I'm thinking of the CLISP, CMUCL, and SBCL repls. Comparing IPython to SLIME is like comparing sed to Emacs. They are not even close to being the same thing, and in any case, neither is the subject of this question.

Comment: @Marcin: My impression is that the CLISP REPL is quite a bit more powerful than what Python provides by default.

Comment: Whether or not it is "more powerful" my experience has not been that it is more useful for interactive development; if anything, the reverse - the additional features interrupt the flow of interaction.

Comment: @Marcin: A bare REPL isn't that usefull, unless you're missing SLIME, but with SLIME it's awesome.

Comment: In addition, it is possible to access the origin of an error in the python interpreter by doing `import pdb; pdb.pm()`. The difference is that python doesn't automatically take you to the debugger by default (which I, for one, prefer).

Comment: It's possible to get to the python debugger automatically if you start  ipython like this: `ipython --pdb`. While I think @RainerJoswig is right, his particular example `(+ a 2)` is not very illustrative IMO.

Answer (score 7):

Python's interactive mode differs from Python's "read code from file" mode in several, small, crucial ways, probably inherent in the textual representation of the language. Python is also not homoiconic, something that makes me call it "interactive mode" rather than "read-eval-print loop". That aside, I'd say that it is more a difference of grade than a difference in kind.

Now, something tahtactually comes close to "difference in kind", in a Python code file, you can easily insert blank lines:

```
def foo(n):
  m = n + 1

  return m
```

If you try to paste the identical code into the interpreter, it will consider the function to be "closed" and complain that you have a naked return statement at the wrong indentation. This does not happen in (Common) Lisp.

Furthermore, there are some rather handy convenience variables in Common Lisp (CL) that are not available (at least as far as I know) in Python. Both CL and Python have "value of last expression" (`*` in CL, `_` in Python), but CL also has `**` (value of expression before last) and `***` (the value of the one before that) and `+`, `++` and `+++` (the expressions themselves). CL also doesn't distinguish between expressions and statements (in essence, everything is an expression) and all of that does help build a much richer REPL experience.

As I said at the beginning, it is more a difference in grade than  difference in kind. But had the gap been only a smidgen wider between them, it would probably be a difference in kind, as well.

Comment: In what way is homoiconicity implicit in the term "read-eval-print loop"?

Comment: @Marcin It is not a strict requirement, but the only time I have heard the term read-eval-print loop has been with homoiconic languages, the rest of them tend to refer to "interactive mode" or "the interpreter" (essentially, if Python has a REPL, so does Sinclair Basic)

Comment: Yes, I think it is fair to say that Sinclair Basic has a REPL.

Comment: Sinclair Basic's interactive prompt is no REPL as it misses the print part. It prints only what you order it to print, and what it prints cannot generally be read back.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: In that case, neither is Python (in Sinclair Basic, "3+4" is not a valid statement (it is, in Python and causes 7 to be written), "LET I=3+4" doesn't print anything and neither does "i=3+4" in Python; the closest Sinclair Basic gets is "PRINT 3+4" and that does, as happens, print 7).

Comment: @Vatine Yes, that's the point we're discussing here: Python's interactive prompt is not a REPL. Also note that Sinclair's prompt is even further away from the REPL: you cannot reuse **anything** it prints. Even the concept of a TTY is missing, where the output history is retained, as if on a continuous-feed printer (the original TTY).